# Mobius transformation for circles

Tags: geometry, mobius-transformation

Let S1, S2, S3 be three nonintersecting circles whose centers do not belong
to one line. Prove that there is a unique circle S orthogonal to S1, S2, S3.

I wanted to use a definition of the Mobius transformation to answer this and the theorem states:

Let S1 and S2 be two nonconcentric circles that do not intersect each
other. Then there are points A and B which are symmetric with respect to S1 and with
respect to S2.

My trouble is extending this definition to three circles instead of two, since I'm assuming their will be different symmetric points for each pair.

Comment: Does the question explicitly require you use symmetric points? For an alternative, say WLOG $S_1$ and $S_2$ are closest, then dilate all the circles by some factor $d$ such that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are now tangent at a point $P$. Invert in a circle $S_4$ centered on $P$ chosen small enough that it doesn't intersect $S_3$ (or our tangent circle $S$). This transforms $S_1$ and $S_2$ into parallel lines $l,m$ and $S_3$ and $S$ into circles $S_5$ and $S'$. The question now asks us to find a circle tangent to two parallel lines and a circle not touching those lines.

Comment: What does "points $A$ and $B$ which are symmetric with respect to $S_1$ and with respect to $S_2$." mean?

Answer (score 2):

Use the concept of
[radical axis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_axis)
line of two circles. The Wikipedia article states:

> In Euclidean geometry, the radical axis of two
> non-concentric circles is the set of points whose
> power with respect to the circles are equal.

Any two circles in general position
have a radical axis in common. For any three circles
$S_1, S_2, S_3$ in general position, the three pairs of
circles correspond to three radical axis lines which
intersect in a common point $P$. This point is the unique
point whose power with respect to each of the circles
are equal. The Wikipedia article also states:

> The radical axis consists of all centers of circles,
> which intersect the given circles orthogonally.

Thus, the point $P$ is also the center of the unique
circle $S$ which is orthogonal to the $S_1,S_2,S_3$
because it is also the center of the circle which passes
through the centers of the three circles.

Comment: why three radical axis lines which intersect in a common point, and why S is also the center of the circle which passes through the centers of the three circles?

Comment: @diiiiiklllllll Thanks for your comment! I have added more info to my answer.